# Possibility of running a MacOS VM at decent speeds on a 3960X

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine, xcode

I wanted to know if I could run a MacOS VM at decent speeds on a System using a Threadripper 3960X. It needs to be fast enogh for me to build iOS Applications on it and run an iPhone Emulator to test them. I will by using Kubuntu on my system and my GPU will be an RTX 3070. Would this be possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience: I have tried running a MacOS VM for development purposes on Kubuntu 20.04, tried both QEMU and Virtual Box methods.  This is on an Intel NUC NUC8i7HVK PC with Radeon RX Vega M GH graphics (decent but still weak compared to any real desktop GPU card of course).

What I found was the graphics run pretty slow (like 2 FPS?) due to my GPU not being supported by passthrough to VM.  This is just too annoying, even for development.  Everything in MacOS appears to use GPU so really you need a GPU that can be directly passed through to the VM AND supported by MacOS. I heard its mainly dedicated AMD GPUs will work well at native speed, not sure about your NVIDIA RTX.  Not sure if your awesome CPU will make up for an unsupported NVIDIA GPU.  Perhaps someone who has attempted it with NVIDIA can comment.